# ZipArchive de PHP no añade nada a el archivo ZIP

Tags: php, laravel, zip

Tengo un problema al cual no encuentro solución y agradezco mucho a quien pueda ayudarme.

Estoy intentando crear un archivo `ZIP` con la extensión **ZipArchive** de **PHP**, en **Laravel 7**, pero no funciona y lo extraño es que no arroja ningún error.

Este es mi código en el Controlador:

```php
  public function DownloadZip($id)
  {
        // Traigo un usuario desde la base de datos
        $user = User::whereId($id)
        ->with('images')
        ->first();
        // Variable con la fecha actual
        $timestamp = now()->format('Y-m-d-H:m:s');
        // Ruta para archivo XLSX que irá en el ZIP
        $excelURL = "tmp/$timestamp-$user->firstname-$user->lastname.xlsx";

        // Almacenó el XLSX con el paquete Maatwebsite\Excel
        Excel::store(new ShowUser($user), $excelURL);

        // Ruta para el archivo ZIP
        $zipURL = storage_path("tmp/$timestamp-$user->firstname-$user->lastname.zip");
        // Creó la instancia de ZipArchive()
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        // Creó el archivo ZIP
        $zipCreate = $zip->open( $zipURL, ZipArchive::CREATE ); // devuelve true

        if($zipCreate){

            foreach($user->images as $item){
                // añado una imagen
                $zip->addFile( storage_path($item->url) ); // no devuelve absolutamente ningún valor
            }

            // Añado el XLSX al ZIP
            $zip->addFile( storage_path($excelURL) ); // no devuelve absolutamente ningún valor

        } else {
            dd('Ocurrio un error..!!');
        }

        // Cierro el ZIP
        $zip->close(); // devuelve true

  }
```

El archivo `XLSX` se crea perfectamente, pero no el `ZIP`. Las imágenes son correctas y la extensión de **PHP** está instalada correctamente *(Cabe destacar que estoy en Ubuntu 20.04)*

[image: Captura de pantalla, phpinfo()]

Espero haberme explicado y que alguien pueda ayudarme. Saludos y gracias de antemano

#### EDIT:

Parece que el problema esta con los permisos que tiene el directorio `storage/app/tmp` que se crea con el archivo **excel**, cambie la ruta por otro directorio y todo funcionó. Mi pregunta ahora es

¿Por qué **ZipArchive** no puede escribir en ese directorio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que fue solo un descuido de mi parte, resulta que los permisos eran correctos, pero de manera tonta no estaba colocando la ruta correctamente en el **helper** `storage_path()`

Lo estaba colocando así:

```php
storage_path("tmp/$timestamp-$user->firstname-$user->lastname.zip");
```

Y la manera correcta era:

```php
storage_path("app/tmp/$timestamp-$user->firstname-$user->lastname.zip");
```

Además de esto, también era necesario crear el directorio `tmp/` ya que no existía y **ZipArchive** no lo crea automáticamente